# ProgressBar2 not working properly in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.8

So, I'm trying to make use of this ProgressBar package in Python. I'm currently using PyCharm 2020.1 (Community Edition) with Python 3.8. For the time being a will have some computation going, everything without logs of prints in the process, and I want a progress bar to keep track of both the status and the Elapsed Time and ETA for this process.
For this, I decided to search for a tool that would do this for me and I found this progressbar2 package at PyPi that implements all of these.
For now, I have a simple code like this:

```
bar = ProgressBar(start=0, maxval=len(data))
i = 0
for d in data[:]:
    # Some computation
    i += 1
    bar.update(i)
bar.finish()
```

Important to mention, I'm trying to call three functions that show a similar progress bar with slightly different values. Nonetheless, following is the result I'm getting with this:

```
[READER] Downloading 506 tickers
100% (506 of 506) |######################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:04 Time:  0:00:04
N/A% (0 of 503) |                        | Elapsed Time: 0:00:00 ETA:  --:--:--[READER] Dumping 503 tickers to CSV
100% (503 of 503) |######################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:03 Time:  0:00:03
N/A% (0 of 503) |                        | Elapsed Time: 0:00:00 ETA:  --:--:--[READER] Compiling 503 tickers
100% (503 of 503) |######################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:06 Time:  0:00:06
```

As you can see, instead of getting only the finished bar and printing the desired string before the start of the next one, I get an inline representation of the next progress bar. Don't know if it is intended to work like that, or if it's either me doing something wrong or compatibility issues with the PyCharm console itself.

Appreciate any suggestions you might have...

UPDATE: Sometimes it works as intended without changing any code or processing in between. Shown below:

```
[READER] Downloading 506 tickers
100% (506 of 506) |######################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:02 Time:  0:00:02
[READER] Dumping 502 tickers to CSV
100% (502 of 502) |######################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:01 Time:  0:00:01
[READER] Compiling 502 tickers
100% (502 of 502) |######################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:03 Time:  0:00:03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

The `progressbar` module had [a known issue with PyCharm](https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar/issues/115). The problem was with the timing between `stderr` and `stdout` which appeared to be fully random causing interleaved results. [It has since been mitigated enough to not be an issue for most people using the `progressbar` module, but it's possible that it's still present](https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar/issues/115#issuecomment-531988743). Since `ProgressBar(start=0, maxval=len(data))` will write to `stderr` and your `print` functions will write to `stdout`, it seems likely that that's the issue.

## Solution

If we assume that that's the problem, you can use a single output stream instead. For example, you could write both to `stdout`:

```py
import sys

# Write ProgressBar to stdout
bar = ProgressBar(start=0, maxval=len(data), fd=sys.stdout)

i = 0
for d in data[:]:
    # Some computation
    i += 1
    bar.update(i)
bar.finish()
```

However, if you insist on using both, [it's been recommended to wait ~200 milliseconds for the next output or it may break](https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar#known-issues). So, in your case, something like:

```py
import time

bar = ProgressBar(start=0, maxval=len(data))
i = 0
for d in data[:]:
    # Some computation
    i += 1
    bar.update(i)
bar.finish()

# Wait 200 milliseconds
time.sleep(0.2)
# Print to stdout
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I've tried the first one and is working perfectly so far. As for the second with the time delay, since I'm developing a program that will eventually run over a real-time system is important that no further things are added that may provide arrears to the execution.